# How to perform A Date Check Between all records of Database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, date

I am working on a hotel management project in which there are two date. One Date is for on which date Room is booked for and other is his departure date. Both of dates are already in database. Now if a new guest Comes and Booked on the same date between these two dates mentioned, then there should be message like Room Booked for the selected date.

Comment: Show us how far you got, and what is not working.
Are you trying a sql procedure, or just c# method?

Comment: I have to perform this operation in my C# project. But i am looking for the logic in my SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: @RahulKumar Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select Count(1) from tablename where getdate() between Startdate and EndDate
```

in your condition check for the count. if count > 0 shoe your message

*tablename = yourtablename

*Startdate and Enddate =change accordingly as per your columnname

UPDATE:

```
select Count(1) from tablename where getdate()>=Startdate and getdate() <= EndDate
```

Comment: It works only on one date but i have to select both dates i.e. Room Booking date and departure date and then i have to check if it conflicts or not.

Comment: wait you just give me a hint

Comment: @RahulKumar that is what I can do as you haven't provided more details. don't forget to mark it as sahi jawab

Comment: sure bhai aisa e hoga

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @bookingDate as datetime ,@roomId as int
Select @bookingDate = '[Insert Date Here]',@roomId = [Enter your roomId]

select 1 as 'booked' from some_table 
where @bookingDate > date_checked_in 
and @bookingDate < date_checked_out
and roomId = @roomId
```

// Perhaps post what the actual table looks like?

Comment: Table is too complicated. just think about two fields  start date and end date

Comment: Then the above might work. You can even turn it into a function that returns a bit value that indicates if the room is available.
ie f_IsRoomAvailable(roomId, Required_Date)
Alternatively, Create a stored proc that returns a list of rooms that is available for specified date.